# Regex to get currency and amount from string

Tags: php, regex

I have an Regex with me `preg_match('/(?<=\$)\d+(\.\d+)?\b/', $str, $regs` which return me the amount in a currency, but what i am trying is to get the symbol associated with the amount too.

1) E.g. the string is `$300.00 asking price` should return $300.00 but now it returns 300 
2) E.g. the string is `EUR 300.00`  should return EUR300.00 but now it returns 300

Simply i want the currency with amount.

Thanks

Comment: Then remove the look-behind assertion and add the EUR case in there.

Answer (score 5):

First, you match the currency which can be either `$` or `EUR`, followed by optional white space:

```
(?:EUR|[$])\s*
```

Then, match the main digit group, followed by an optional period and two digits:

```
\d+(?:\.\d{2})?
```

In total we get this:

```
$pattern = '/(?:EUR|[$])\s*\d+(?:\.\d{2})?/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$str = "$300.00 asking price";
preg_match('/^([\$]|EUR|€)\s*([0-9,\s]*\.?[0-9]{0,2})?+/', $str, $regs);
```

#### Outputs

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '$300.00' (length=7)
  1 => string '$' (length=1)
  2 => string '300.00' (length=6)

array (size=3)
  0 => string 'EUR 300.00' (length=10)
  1 => string 'EUR' (length=3)
  2 => string '300.00' (length=6)
```

Comment: This will match strange things like `EUR 30 0,0 .`

Comment: I don't think that should be a valid amount though; see [this example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RLKRS3).

Comment: You don't need to escape `$` inside the character class, [see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
/(\$|EUR)\s*(\d*\.\d+)?\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the amount part for any Symbol :

```
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+[.]*)/", $t, $output_array);
$output_array=implode("",$output_array[0]);
```

***" €12451.5651$Euro " will output: 12451.5651***